# windows 7 - deleted folder reappear

Tags: windows-7

Recently bought a new computer and started using windows 7.  I noticed that in my documents that there are folders that are already there - eg. favorites, downloads etc - these folders are empty.  I've tried deleting them but they reappear after I reboot/restart my computer.  Any suggestions as to why they reappear or how to get rid of them.  I've owned the computer for 3 days now.

Comment: Downloads is the default download location for IE, Chrome, etc.  Favorites are where your IE bookmarks go...

Comment: This is normal behavior and is just part of the Users folder hierarchy.

Answer (score 4):

Those folders are part of the OS (Operating System). You **cannot** delete them.

Comment: Or maybe you *can* remove them, but you *shouldn't*. After all, some parts of OS rely on them, and by the way, those folders do not spend any disk space.

Comment: Yea your right.